# Creating a script for error logging

Tags: php

I'd like to have on one of my personal website the possibility to personalize the errors: I mean, I'd like to show nothing on the video, when an error occurs, but to log all errors on a simple text file, as it always should be done in production.

I know that there are 4 levels which you can act on, to do that,  and these have a different priority.
I mean you can't overwrite a directive that has been set in php.ini with a “runtime” file in PHP that you can put on webpage using the functions error_reporting(),  and ini_set().

If I don't make a mistake, these are the 4 levels (from the most important one):

**1) the php.ini**

**2) the httpd.conf**

**3) a .htaccess file to be put in the document root that's /**

**4) and finally a PHP file using the predefined functions error_reporting(), and ini_set()**

My problem is on my web server where I 've got my site.  I want to use the 4th solution showed above, and I prepared this php file that I tried to put online on a page of mine,  this way:

```
<?php
include 'err_produ.php';
?>
```

The source of it, is:

```
<?php
 /*

 This is for PRODUCTION.

 Report all errors but show nothing on video: use the error_log file instead.


 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');  
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);  
ini_set('log_errors', 1);  
ini_set('log_errors_max_len', 0);   
ini_set('ignore_repeated_errors', 1);  
ini_set('ignore_repeated_source', 1);  
ini_set('report_memleaks', 1);  
ini_set('track_errors', 1);  
ini_set('error_log', './error_log2');  
 ?>
```

The strangest thing is that if I make a mistake, writing for example an uninitialized variable, I still see on the screen the error!!!!

and on my error_log2 file I see absolutely nothing at all!

I tried on my local web server that file (I got Xampp on my Ubuntu) and it works perfectly: on the screen I see nothing, and on my error_log2 file I see all errors.

Can anybody help me, please?

I do think that on my web server where I have my site, the directives are set within the php.ini and I can't  access that. In fact it's a shared web server that gives hosting for free.

If  it is so, I' m not allowed to use a file like the one I wrote, to act runtime.

What do you think?
Thanks.